# Mixture Problem with Removing part

Tags: word-problem

```
How much antifreeze which is 30% alcohol must be removed
from a 48-ounce container and replaced with water to make 48 ounces of a
solution which is 20% alcohol?
```

I am not getting jist of above problem as to how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Initially, $30\%$ of the $48$ ounce solution is alcohol.  How much alcohol does it contain?  After some of the alcohol has been replaced by water, $20\%$ of the $48$ ounce solution is alcohol.  How much alcohol remains?  Therefore, how much alcohol has been replaced by water? Keep in mind that the amount of alcohol that has been replaced is $30\%$ of the anti-freeze that has been replaced.

**Answer:**  (using the hint)  Initially, the amount of alcohol is $30\%$ of the $48~\text{oz}$ solution, which is $$0.3 \cdot 48~\text{oz} = 14.4~\text{oz}$$ The final amount of alcohol is $20\%$ of the $48~\text{oz}$ solution, which is $$0.2 \cdot 48~\text{oz} = 9.6~\text{oz}$$  The amount of alcohol that has been removed is $$14.4~\text{oz} - 9.6~\text{oz} = 4.8~\text{oz}$$  Since the amount of alcohol that is removed is $30\%$ of the amount of anti-freeze that has been removed and replaced by water, the amount of anti-freeze that has been replaced by water is $$\frac{10}{3} \cdot 4.8~\text{oz} = 16~\text{oz}$$

**Alternate Solution:** Let $x$ be the amount of anti-freeze that has been removed.  Then the volume of anti-freeze that remains before the water is added is $48~\text{oz} - x$, of which $30\%$ is alcohol.  After the water is added, the new volume is $48~\text{oz}$, of which $20\%$ is alcohol.  Since adding water does not change the amount of alcohol in the solution, 
\begin{align*}
0.3(48~\text{oz} - x) & = 0.2 \cdot 48~\text{oz}\\
14.4~\text{oz} - 0.3x & = 9.6~\text{oz}\\
4.8~\text{oz} & = 0.3x\\
16~\text{oz} & = x
\end{align*}
which agrees with the previous result.

Comment: Did not get it.First value is 14.4 then what.........?

Comment: @khan  I have edited my answer to include the details of the solution.  I have also provided a more efficient alternate solution.  I hope at least one of the methods makes sense.

Comment: Your alternate solution is awesome!

Comment: @khan  Needless to say, I did not think of the alternate solution until after I wrote the hint for the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved with the allegation and mixture method, where we find out the distance from both the %.

Antifreeze has 30% alcohol and water has 0%. We need to make average to be 20%. That means we must take them in some proportion. This ratio will be  $30$%-$20$% : $20$%-$0$%. That is $1:2$. It means that we should have 1 liter of water for every two liters of antifreeze. In the question, after the removal and mixture, the final volume is $48$ oz, which must have the ratio of antifreeze to water as 2:1. Hence water is $16$ oz. This $16$ oz came after removal. Therefore this must be the amount removed.